# C# dynamic field depending on "T" type, without hardcoding

Tags: c#, .net, generics

So I have a function. It takes in an object called 'item' of an unknown type. In the function, it declares an object, and depending on what the Type is, depends on what field of 'item' the object gets a value from, for example:

```
private static void CreateObject<T>(T item)
{
    SomeObject object = new SomeObject();

    //if 'item' is type "A"
    //          object.Text = item.Display
    //else if 'item' is type "B"
    //          object.Text = item.Text
    //else if 'item' is type "C"
    //          object.Text = item.Value


}
```

Please note, passing the string of 'item.display' or which ever is not an option, as alot goes on in this function, and this is a simplified version of the function for explaining whats required.

How could this be done in a more elegant way?

I have looked at reflection but been instructed to avoid this as it is expensive (hardware, memory etc)

Answer (score 4):

Take a delegate parameter that will provide the `Text`

```
private static void CreateObject<T>(T item, Func<T, object> prop)
{
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();

    obj.Text = prop(item).ToString();
}
```

So the caller of the method will use

```
CreateObject(a, t => t.Display);
CreateObject(b, t => t.Text);
// etc
```

Comment: Should that be Func<T, object>, Or perhaps even Func<T, string> so the caller can handle the ToString() appropriately?

Comment: @ChrisSainty Yes. Thanks for noticing that. I accidentally switched the parameters

Comment: The OP says: "Please note, passing the string of 'item.display' or which ever is not an option, as alot goes on in this function, and this is a simplified version of the function for explaining whats required." which means that it's not just a matter of getting a single string, but perhaps a number of additional parameters. Having a delegate for each one is a mess.

Comment: @siride OP will decide whether a simple lambda expression is a mess or not. In your solution where do you new up the adapter? that same line is replaced by the lamda.

Comment: @Eranga I don't see the relevance of which line the object creation happens on. The point is that with your method, you'd have to create a number of delegates (a number that could change in the future if more things are needed from the CreateObject method), whereas with an adapter, the call-site is cleaned and the new functionality is properly organized in classes, instead of muddled onto one ugly line.

Comment: @siride not necessarily. You can supply a method that matches the signature of the delegate without having to implement interfaces to just to call a method with adapter.

Comment: @Eranga and where do all those methods go? You'll end up recreating the adapter pattern but without having it be properly organized into classes. That's my whole point.

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the adapter pattern and pass in an adapter object that will return display text and other things. That object can be constructed by the caller as appropriate (presumably, the caller will know more about the nature of the object it is sending in to `CreateObject()`). Examples:

```
interface IMyAdapter {
    string GetDisplayText();
    // ...
}

class TextBoxAdapter : IMyAdapter {
    private readonly TextBox tb;

    public TextBoxAdapter(TextBox tb) {
        this.tb = tb;
    }

    public string GetDisplayText() {
        return tb.Text;
    }

    // ...
}

...

public static void CreateObject(IAdapter adapter) {
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
    obj.Text = adapter.GetDisplayText();
    // ...
}

...

var textBoxAdapter = new TextBoxAdapter(new TextBox());
CreateObject(textBoxAdapter);
```

Comment: +1 - yes, adapter pattern will work but accepting a delegate is far more convenient!

Comment: @VinayC: the OP wants to do more than just return a single value. He said that just passing in the string, for example, is not enough, which I took to mean that other values would be gathered from the object. He'd have to pass in multiple delegates, which gets messy fast.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Eranga's answer about passing a delegate, if you do not want to litter delegates all over your calling code you could create non-generic overloads for this function to do it for you.

```
private static void CreateObject<T>(T item, Func<T, string> prop) {
  SomeObject obj = new SomeObject();
  obj.Text = prop(item);
}

private static void CreateObject(TypeA item) {
  CreateObject(item, i => i.Display);
}

private static void CreateObject(TypeB item) {
  CreateObject(item, i => i.Text);
}
```

This would centralise the delegates, while still pulling it away from the middle of the body of your function.

I think to give the "best" answer though, we would need to know a lot more about the size and purpose of this method, where it is being called from etc.

There are many ways you could approach this, and honestly under some circumstances there would be nothing wrong with your series of if statements. It is clear, any programmer should understand it and if you only have a couple of cases just do it and get on with solving real problems.

Comment: Notice that this requires that the class containing `CreateObject()` knows about all possible types that are passed in. I don't think that's the best design and I think if the OP had intended for it to be just one or two types, he'd have already used this pattern instead of having a generic method.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the "best" approach depends on aspects of the code that have not been shared. I posted my answer to simply highlight another option. It is for the OP to decide which approach suits their application.